# Pytest spending most time post-test?

Tags: python, pytest, profiling

I run a single function through `pytest` that (in the example below) takes 71 seconds to run. However, `pytest` spends an additional 6-7 minutes doing... something. I can tell from a log file that the intended test is executed at the beginning of the 7 minutes, but I cannot imagine what's going on afterwards (and apparently it's not the teardown, if the "slowest durations" output is to be believed).

The pytest function itself is extremely minimal:

```
def test_preprocess_and_train_model():
    import my_module.pipeline as pipeline  # noqa

    pipeline.do_pipeline(do_s3_upload=False,
                         debug=True, update_params={'tf_verbosity': 0})
```

If I run `test_preprocess_and_train_model()` by hand (e.g., if I invoke the function through an interpreter rather than through `pytest`), it takes about 70 seconds.

What is happening and how can I speed it up?

```
▶  pytest --version
pytest 6.2.2
▶ python --version
Python 3.8.5
▶ time pytest -k test_preprocess_and_train_model -vv --durations=0                                             
====================================================== test session starts =======================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.8.5, pytest-6.2.2, py-1.9.0, pluggy-0.13.1 -- /usr/local/opt/python@3.8/bin/python3.8
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /Users/blah_blah_blah/tests
collected 3 items / 2 deselected / 1 selected                                                                                    

test_pipelines.py::test_preprocess_and_train_model PASSED                                                                  [100%] 

======================================================== warnings summary ========================================================
test_pipelines.py::test_preprocess_and_train_model
  /Users/your_name_here/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py:22: DeprecationWarning: the imp module is deprecated in favour of importlib; see the module's documentation for alternative uses
    import imp

test_pipelines.py: 3604341 warnings
  sys:1: DeprecationWarning: PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN will be required for '#' formats

test_pipelines.py::test_preprocess_and_train_model
  /Users/your_name_here/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:2325: UserWarning: `Model.state_updates` will be removed in a future version. This property should not be used in TensorFlow 2.0, as `updates` are applied automatically.
    warnings.warn('`Model.state_updates` will be removed in a future version. '

-- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/warnings.html
======================================================= slowest durations ========================================================
71.88s call     test_pipelines.py::test_preprocess_and_train_model
0.00s teardown test_pipelines.py::test_preprocess_and_train_model
0.00s setup    test_pipelines.py::test_preprocess_and_train_model
================================= 1 passed, 2 deselected, 3604343 warnings in 422.15s (0:07:02) ==================================
pytest -k test_preprocess_and_train_model -vv --durations=0  305.95s user 158.42s system 104% cpu 7:26.14 total
```

Comment: Are you able to post the code under test and the test itself?

Comment: Dear @MarcelloRomani, the test itself is only one line and invokes a secondary script. Unfortunately, I can't include that code (it's proprietary), but it amounts to training a TensorFlow model and uploading some data to S3. As the output above shows, though, the call itself is only 71.88 seconds.

Comment: I just tried suppressing the S3 upload; the problem persisted.

Comment: Four more factoids: First, after 70 seconds, pytest prints "PASSED" to the screen. Second, during the extra 6 minutes, pytest keeps one of my processors at 100% CPU usage. Third, I'm testing on MacOS 11.2.2; running on Ubuntu, I don't observe the problem. Fourth, the observant reader may notice the 3.6 million (!) error messages above; running with "--disable-warnings" does not change anything.

Comment: not sure how someone can help you without showing us some code or a reproducible example. it's just a guessing game at that point.

Comment: Ah, @gold_cy, perhaps you're right. I was hoping for some insight into what pytest does after it completes a test. Again, the test clearly takes 70-ish seconds-- pytest is doing *something else* for the remainder of the time, and I'm too ignorant to imagine what.

Comment: A good question to ask may be: if you put the test code into its own script and run it directly, does it still exhibit the slowness? Perhaps there's an `atexit` handler being executed, which might be registered by TensorFlow or some other 3rd-party lib.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @theY4Kman; I tried that when I ran it with the interpreter, and it only took the 70 seconds.

Comment: Well, in that case, profiling the pytest session would be my next step. pytest can be invoked under cProfile with `python -m cProfile -o pytest.prof -m pytest -k test_preprocess_and_train_model`, and the resulting profile results can be visualized/inspected with SnakeViz – https://jiffyclub.github.io/snakeviz/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought I'd post the resolution of this in case it helps anyone else.

theY4Kman's suggestion of just profiling the code was excellent. My own code ran in 70 seconds as expected and exited cleanly, but it produced 3.6M warning messages. Each warning message in pytest triggered an os.stat() check (to figure out which line of code had produced the warning), and evaluating 3.6M system calls took 5 minutes or so. If I commented out the heart of `warning_record_to_str()` in pytest's `warnings.py`, then pytest took about 140 seconds (i.e., most of the problem was solved).

This also explained why the performance depended on the platform (Mac vs Ubuntu), because the number of error messages differed vastly.

There seem to be two sad conclusions, if I'm understanding things correctly:

- Even if I use the `--disable-warnings` flag, it appears that pytest happily collects all the warnings, stats them, etc; it just doesn't print them.  In my case, that meant that pytest spent 85% of its time computing information that it immediately discarded.
- The `os.stat()` check occurs inside Python's `linecache.py` function. Since I had an identical warning 3.6M times, I expected the function would run `os.stat()` once and cache the result, but that did not happen. I assume I'm just misunderstanding something basic about the intended use of this function.